# "It was nice meeting you or it was nice talking to you", What's the grammar?

Tags: adjectives, adverbial-phrases, present-participles

I'm not sure about this thing, but it has been tormenting me for a while. I can't really understand the grammatical structure of **it was nice meeting you**.

I mean, if **nice** in itself is an adjective, then how is it modifying meeting?

But if we remove **nice**, then the sentence **It was meeting you** doesn't make much more of the sense of what we are trying to express, instead it just forms a past continuous tense.

However, this thing **it was nice meeting you** holds the ground if we consider meeting as a noun i.e. a  gerund. Can anyone explain to me what's actually happening over here?

Comment: A related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/verb-adverb-clause-ing

Answer (score 0):

Adjectives can take different complements : PP (preposition+gerund); 'to'-infinitive , 'gerund', or a clause.

> Adjectives + preposition + gerund

*"During the lockdown we are bored of doing nothing."*

> Adjective + to-infinitive

*"It would be wonderful to meet you again."*
(Meeting didn't take place at the time of speaking.)

> Adjective + gerund

*"It was wonderful meeting you again yesterday."*
(Meeting took place yesterday.)

Similarly, **"Nice to meet you"** is used at the very beginning of the meeting as an introductory part.

**"It was nice meeting you"** means the meeting already took place & it was a nice experience.

Comment: Thanks for the response there. But how do we justify that it is a gerund in the sentence, not a present participle? does simply putting an adjective before the present particle makes it a gerund?

Comment: No, it's gerund because it serves as a noun in apposition to the pronoun 'it'. Here, it = meeting you. You can replace 'it'with "meeting you" : Meeting you was nice.

Comment: I had known that appositives follow the noun they modify or provide essential information about. And I have already thought about, "it = meeting you" but couldn't really figure out the reason behind it. Do you, Sandip, mind providing me with a link or an article, where I can read more about it?